# fopen() returning null, with invalid argument error

Tags: c, file, fopen

I have a very simple program `prog.c`:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  char * file_path = argv[2];
  FILE * fp = fopen(file_path, "-rb");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("\nerror");
  }
}
```

I compile the program with
`gcc -o prog prog.c -lrt`
and run with
`./prog --file Tiny.txt`

and `prog` and `Tiny.txt` are both directly under the `src` directory (both are at the same level). I cannot see why `fopen` is giving me an invalid argument error.

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: What is `"-rb"` supposed to be?

Comment: My initial thought was to downvote this question, because I think attention to detail, thorough consciously character-by-character checking of code, and carefully reading the documentation are important parts of software development. But then I remembered that human error being possible without deliberate effort to do the wrong thing is almost always a sign that something is bad in the API design or in the constraints that shape the API.

Comment: Basically I'm saying that a good API (one designed with attention to everything we've learned about best practices for making code human friendly and improving developer experience) doesn't leave a user wondering "why am I getting this error", because the error clearly tells you, and is harder to make accidentally.

Comment: Of course C's standard library pre-dates a lot of this wisdom, and pre-dates a lot of the capabilities in systems and programming languages and tooling, which is a big part of why C's `fopen` API is decent for its time. I'm just saying, before you judge this question as bad on the asker's part, or downvote it based on that, (as I was tempted to do), remember that we are here because the error is less than optimally helpful, because this high-ish-level interface did not wrap an old low-level errors-are-integer-codes design decision, because the error is not diagnosed until runtime, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I just realized I used a `-` in `-rb`. It should simply be `rb`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have used an invalid character in the open mode parameter, the error message is clear, a parameter is invalid, the first is a file name, which allows anything to be put inside... so look at the only other parameter you have.  The `'-'` finally was the guilty.

Answer (score 1):

There should be:

```
FILE * fp = fopen(file_path, "rb");
```

instead of:

```
FILE * fp = fopen(file_path, "-rb");
```